# iOS Weather Like Navigation Component

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm trying to find the control that enables the horizontal scrolling with little dot navigation like the weather app has in iOS.

I can't seem to find it, and I'm assuming it exists because I see the exact same implementation in a ton of apps.

Bonus points if you can link to a Xamarin or Objective-C example (Xamarin preferred).

[image: weather app navigation]

Comment: UIPageViewController...http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/

Comment: @danh Wonderful! You should answer this so I can mark your answer as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the UIPageViewController component, which is documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

...and a thorough example follows below:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_7_UIPageViewController_Application

Hope this provides the functionality you're looking for, but I'm pretty sure it's the same component.